# Struts 2 - Action already executed exception

Tags: java, exception, struts2, struts

Sometimes, this exception is thrown in my struts 2 application.
Can't replicate it when I want, it just pops out randomly.

```
Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:   
Action has already executed
File:   com/opensymphony/xwork2/DefaultActionInvocation.java
Line number:    240

Stacktraces
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action has already executed

com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:240)
xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq.ddd.interceptors.AuthInterceptor.invoke(AuthInterceptor.java:68)
xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq.ddd.interceptors.AuthCCareInterceptor.checkAuthenticateInvoke(AuthCCareInterceptor.java:142)
xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq.ddd.interceptors.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.java:59)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Sorry for the "xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq.ddd" but it is confidential information. I'm sure you understand!

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that we were saving variables in the interceptor, such as the action instance that was invoked. After a refactoring everything started to work normally!

Interceptors need to be thread-safe (like servlets).

Comment: Good work :) Tracking that kind of thing down can be frustrating.

Comment: @miguel Ribeiro what you mean refactoring? I got the same issue can you elaborate?

Comment: @miguel Ribeiro I did use this method `invokeActionOnly()` it worked fine.

Comment: @Babel uuuh... this was a long time ago! Can't remember very well but it had something to do with keeping the action instance as class variable in the interceptor I think. Sorry can't be more helpful

Answer (score 3):

One of these three interceptors is likely broken:

```
interceptors.AuthInterceptor.invoke(AuthInterceptor.java:68)
interceptors.AuthCCareInterceptor.checkAuthenticateInvoke(AuthCCareInterceptor.java:142)
interceptors.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.java:59)
```

Obviously can't tell you much beyond that with the information provided.

Comment: Well, I thought that there may be a reason for this happen. If it was a broken interceptor, shouldn't I be able to reproduce the error performing the exact same action?

Comment: Depends on how it's broken, I suppose. There's a lot of moving parts, but since I've been working w/ S2, I've *never* seen this--it certainly *could* be something in the framework, but w/o more info, I wouldn't know how to find out.

Comment: What kind of information you think it would help to identify the problem? :-P

Comment: Not sure--hmm, why is the AuthInterceptor in that trace twice?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm no pro in struts 2, but maybe due to inheritance since AuthCCareInterceptor extends AuthInterceptor

Comment: I'd check the flow through those interceptors pretty carefully, make sure they're thread-safe, etc.

Comment: Dave Newton, that was exactly the problem. We were saving variables private variables, such the action instance that was invoked!

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro Glad you worked  it out! I think answering your own question and accepting it would be reasonable, since I didn't really provide any specifics. But yep, interceptors are like servlets in that you have to be careful with instance variables.